# Реализация Downloader`а на Android

Tags: android, база-данных

Здравствуйте, уважаемые пользователи сего форума. Возникла у меня задача одна. Необходимо создать android-приложение, которое будет подключаться к БД PostgresSql (на сервере) и скачивать оттуда книги (да, книги хранятся в БД). В этих вопросах я не очень разбираюсь. Можно ли как-то подключиться с android к Postgres и искать необходимые книги с помощью sql-запросов ? Или же это должны быть веб-сервисы. Прошу подсказать с чего начать и что изучать. Спасибо.

Comment: В общем тут начать и кончить. Это целую поэму надо писать, начните с малого как подключиться к Postgres из Android'а - это само по себе не так то просто :)

Comment: @Barmaley, Да я с момента написания сего поста перерыл уже кучу информации. Понял, что лучше всего использовать Веб Сервисы или же Restful API, теперь вот думаю как все связать в кучу )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начните с Restful сервера, который отвечает json'ами на запросы от устройства. Устройство далее парсит json строки и выдает на UI результаты. Вам надо разработать лексику запросов к серверу. Типа:

```
 https://myhost.com/library?list=all&sort=descending
```

выдает список всех книг сортированных по убыванию.

Или:

```
https//myhost.com/library?bookid=123
```

Возвращает контент книги с идентификатором 123

Посмотрите как организованы  API других сервисов, например Flickr.com - публичный фотохостинг с Restful сервисом

На стороне сервера должен быть некий бэкенд который поступающие get/post запросы правильно транслирует в SQL к Postgres и возвращает результаты клиенту в виде json строки.

Как то так.